ArgoCD gitlab scmProvider and labelMatch filter
I am trying to add a filters: labelMatch to my ArgoCD ApplicationSet.
I have gitlab project label deploy-ok (I tried setting a project topic too) but the labelMatch filter matching this label is not picking up any project.
When I specify labelMatch: .* all the repos are automatically deployed as Argo Applications.
I wonder if there is an issue with the gitlab scmProvider and labels or what I am doing wrong.
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: k8s-apps-applicationset
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  generators:
    - scmProvider:
        gitlab:
          api: "https://gitlab.com/api/v4"
          group: "my-group"
          insecure: false
          tokenRef:
            secretName: "argocd-gitlab-credentials"
            key: "password"
        filters:
          - repositoryMatch: .*
            labelMatch: deploy-ok
  template:
    metadata:
      name: "{{ repository }}"
    spec:
      project: "default"
      source:
        repoURL: "https://gitlab.com/my-group/{{ repository }}.git"
        targetRevision: "main"
        path: "."
      destination:
        server: "https://kubernetes.default.svc"
        namespace: apps
          syncPolicy:
        automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true

pod logs
level=info msg="generated 0 applications" applicationset=argocd/k8s-apps-applicationset generator="{nil nil nil &SCMProviderGenerator{Github:nil,Gitlab:&SCMProviderGeneratorGitlab{Group:my-group,IncludeSubgroups:false,API:https://gitlab.com/api/v4,TokenRef:&SecretRef{SecretName:argocd-gitlab-credentials,Key:password,},AllBranches:false,Insecure:false,IncludeSharedProjects:nil,Topic:,},Bitbucket:nil,BitbucketServer:nil,Gitea:nil,AzureDevOps:nil,Filters:[]SCMProviderGeneratorFilter{SCMProviderGeneratorFilter{RepositoryMatch:*.*,PathsExist:[],PathsDoNotExist:[],LabelMatch:*deploy-ok,BranchMatch:nil,},},CloneProtocol:,RequeueAfterSeconds:nil,Template:ApplicationSetTemplate{ApplicationSetTemplateMeta:ApplicationSetTemplateMeta{Name:,Namespace:,Labels:map[string]string{},Annotations:map[string]string{},Finalizers:[],},Spec:ApplicationSpec{Source:nil,Destination:ApplicationDestination{Server:,Namespace:,Name:,},Project:,SyncPolicy:nil,IgnoreDifferences:[]ResourceIgnoreDifferences{},Info:[]Info{},RevisionHistoryLimit:nil,Sources:[]ApplicationSource{},},},Values:map[string]string{},AWSCodeCommit:nil,} nil nil nil nil nil nil}" time="2024-10-31T12:09:29Z" level=info msg="end reconcile" applicationset=argocd/k8s-apps-applicationset requeueAfter=30m0s

